# Como retornar dados da api traduzidos com i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Minha API retorna dados serializados com `active_model_serializers`, alguns destes atributos são traduzidos no frontend utilizando `angular-translate`.

O dicionário contendo as traduções está cada vez maior, desejo fazer a tradução desses dados no backend e já retornar traduzido estes dados.

A forma que encontrei foi através da camada de serializers definindo métodos com cada atributo e os traduzindo.

Desejo a opinião de outros que efetivaram algo similar em seus projetos.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando o comando do ruby `eval` você consegue criar os métodos de maneira dinâmica dentro da aplicação...

Crie as traduções normalmente, e utilize este método dentro da sua classe para retorná-las...
Por exemplo...

```
name = ['traducao 1', 'traducao 2']
name.each do |name|
 eval("def #{name}?
   I18n.t('name')
 end")
end
```

Acho que isso ajuda, se eu pensar em outra solução posto aqui, valeu!!

Answer (score 0):

A forma que encontrei para resolver a questão, foi definindo método por método para cada atributo. Veja abaixo o código:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class User
  class RolesSerializer < ApplicationSerializer # :nodoc:
    attributes :name

    def name
      I18n.t object.name, scope: 'roles'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Gostaria muito de uma forma mais eficaz para essa questão.